# iPhone Symbol Not Found Error on Device when Using PLCameraView

Tags: iphone

I can deploy an application via SSH to a jailbroken device. I sign it with ldid, but when I try to run it i get:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCameraController
Referenced from: /private/var/stash/Applications.pwn/iPhoneCam.app/iPhoneCam
Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap
```

error. The code I run is;

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
// Override point for customization after app launch    
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

// Get the view for preview and start preview 
PLCameraController *cam = [PLCameraController sharedInstance]; 
UIView *view = [cam previewView]; 
[cam startPreview]; 

// Add the preview view to window 
[window addSubview:view]; 

// Override point for customization after app launch 
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
}
```

taken from [here](http://mobile-augmented-reality.blogspot.com/2009/05/iphoneusing-plcameracontroller.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it; somehow I need to call the object as:

```
objc_getClass("PLCameraController")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just require a 'full screen' camera view, you can just subclass the `UIImagePickerController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
[self setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self setShowsCameraControls:FALSE];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
}
```

From SDK3.1, you can use the `cameraOverlayView` property to set custom camera UI controls.

The `setFrame` does not make the actual camera view full screen - I don't believe that's possible really - so I guess you could leave that out just as well.